# Python2.7: Trying to pickle set of custom objects

Tags: python, pickle

I'm sort of a python nub, so bear with me. I have a set of custom classes, each of which basically wraps and adds some functionality to an image file that's been converted to a `numpy.ndarray`. Since it takes about 2 minutes to create all these objects each time the script is run, I was hoping to create a list of them and pickle that list. The pickling seems to go well; the unpickling fails.

This is all I'm doing:

**Pickling**

```
        frame_jar_file = open(os.path.join(asset_path, "frame_jar.pkl"), "w+")
        for x in range(1, 500):
            path = os.path.join(img_path, "{0}.jpg".format(str(x).zfill(8)))
            surface = NumpySurface(path)
            self.scene_surfaces.append(surface)

        frame_jar = cPickle.Pickler(frame_jar_file, -1)  # have tried this with no protocol arg as well
        frame_jar.dump(self.scene_surfaces)
        frame_jar_file.close()
        exit()
```

Produces a file about 2gb in size, which seems about right to me given the data.

**Unpickling**

```
self.scene_surfaces = cPickle.Unpickler(os.path.join(asset_path, "frame_jar.pkl"))
```

Provokes this error:

```
TypeError: argument must have 'read' and 'readline' attributes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in an *open file object*, not the filename:

```
with open(os.path.join(asset_path, "frame_jar.pkl"), 'rb') as infh:
    unpickler = cPickle.Unpickler(infh)
    self.scene_surfaces = unpickler.load()
```

I also assumed you wanted to load the data, not just create an unpickler.

Comment: /facepalm Right. So I can't unpickle a string, basically, is what you're saying. All the sighs. Thank you. :)

Comment: @Jonline: the unpickler cannot read the pickle data from a string. :-)